# No mysql password under linux?

Tags: linux, passwords, mysql

I was told that mysql user, similar to root user, by default "has no password".

Not an empty password, but rather "no password". I wasn't aware this situation was possible - I thought every user on a linux had to have a password.

Am I wrong? Can you point me to a link that explain this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you add a user in unix, ever notice how it doesn't prompt you for a password? Try it: `useradd testuser`. Didn't ask did it? Just gave you a new command prompt. Congratulations, now you have a user with no password.

Of course, you can't log in using the user until you set a password for it, so it's not much of a security hole. This is the reason the mysql user is set up with no password: if it HAD a default password it would be a MASSIVE security hole, because you'd be able to log in using that user and have rights over the database.

If you look in your /etc/shadow file, you should see the user with a ! where the password would otherwise be. Means the account is locked.

Comment: Any proof from official document ?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of users on a Linux system that are necessary for proper operation of the OS which are not meant to be logins. None of these should have a password.